# Unique timer for each CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uicollectionview

I'm building a chat app and want to include an auto delete feature for messages, if a switch is turned on. So far my code works for one message at a time, but when you send 2 or more messages before the first timer has completed they seem to interfer with eachother, eventhough the Timer object is declared inside each cell.

Inside the collectionView at cellForItem I setup the cells, where I check if the switch is on

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

        if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "autoDeletion") as? Bool ?? false
        {
            cell.addAutoDeletionTimer()
        }
```

So if it's on I execute addAutoDeletionTimer() function which is in the ChatMessageCell class, it looks like this:

```
var deletionTimer: Timer?
var timeLeft = 0

func addAutoDeletionTimer()
{
    autoDeletionTimerLabel.isHidden = false
    let currentTime = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    let deletionTime = message?.autoDeletion?.intValue
    timeLeft = deletionTime! - currentTime
    if timeLeft > 1
    {
        deletionTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(autoDeletionTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    else
    {
        self.chatLogController?.removeMessage(message: message!)
    }
}

@objc func autoDeletionTimer()
{
    timeLeft -= 1
    if timeLeft < 1
    {
        deletionTimer?.invalidate()
        self.chatLogController?.removeMessage(message: message!)
    }
    autoDeletionTimerLabel.text = String(timeLeft)
}
```

Basically the message object has a property called autoDeletion which is a timerIntervalSince1970 + 120 for example. So the message will be deleted 2 minutes after it's sent.

As I said, this works if I only send 1 message, and wait for that message to get deleted. My question would be how to create a unique timer for each cell, which will not interfer with each other?
Or is there a better solution to this?

My message object:

```
class Message: NSObject
{
    var fromId: String?
    var text: String?
    var timestamp: NSNumber?
    var autoDeletion: NSNumber?
    var imageUrl: String?
    var videoUrl: String?
    var imageWidth: NSNumber?
    var imageHeight: NSNumber?
    var messageId: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: Any])
    {
        self.fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String
        self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String
        self.timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? NSNumber
        self.imageUrl = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String
        self.videoUrl = dictionary["videoUrl"] as? String
        self.imageWidth = dictionary["imageWidth"] as? NSNumber
        self.imageHeight = dictionary["imageHeight"] as? NSNumber
        self.autoDeletion = dictionary["autoDeletion"] as? NSNumber
        self.messageId = dictionary["messageId"] as? String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If autoDeletion is on, how about using [performSelector:withObject:AfterDelay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-performselector) to call a function that takes this message object as an argument and removes it from the array of messages (`self.chatLogController?.removeMessage(message: message!)` )and reloads the table view. That way you don't have to deal with timers or invalidating them.

Remember to call performSelector, when you receive the message object, that way messages are deleted after appropriate intervals from when they are received

Comment: This would work I think, the problem is I really want to keep the visual aspect of the timer counting down on each chat message cell.